# Adding String and Int to the same List

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am trying to figure out how to add dept and courseNum to the courses List.

```
    List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();

    String userChoice = "";

    while (!MENU[MENU.length - 1].equals(userChoice)) {
        userChoice = Utils.userChoose(kybd, MENU);

        // "Create Course",
        if (MENU[0].equals(userChoice)) {
            System.out.print("What's the department? ");
            String dept = kybd.next();
            System.out.print("What's the course number? ");
            int courseNum = kybd.nextInt();
            // Add course to user's courses here.
        }
```

I have tried

```
    Collections.addAll(courses, dept, courseNum);
```

And

```
    courses.add(dept);
    courses.add(courseNum);
```

But there are errors with each statement.

Comment: Can you show what the `Course` class looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array list is a list of course objects so you cannot add int or string types to it. instead you must create new Course objects, set the course number and department fields on them and then add the Course object to the list.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can add new member variables *courseNum* and *dept* to the Course class. That way these attributes can be associated with a particular course. Also add *setCourseNum* and *setDept* methods to set those attributes.

Answer (score 0):

List class allows you to add Java objects as part of the list, this meaning you can add a course object that has values like "time, date, courseNum, id, professor" and so on.

I suggest you try to add the department and any other value you want to the same object.